# smart table and output format of numbers

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I got simple UI5-app with a CDS-View as a sata source.

Everything works fine except one thing. Some numbers are displayed with 3 digits after decimal point:

[image]

But in my CDS-View this data has totally different type (5 digits before decimal point and 2 after ):

[image]

As far I know:

- I can't use formatter in my frontend because it's a UI5 Smart Table and I 
  don't have binding
- I can't do anything in my XML-View either, because of the smart table

What I was thinking of are some CDS-Annotations for such a formatting, but I could not find any for my case.

How would you guys solve this problem?

Comment: There is a hint in the [guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/formatting-numbers/). Quotation: "If you need to display decimal numbers, use float and keep the number of digits after the decimal point to a minimum". Maybe that will help?

Comment: thanks for reply! Yes, when I change the data type of the table field to the float it works fine. But I still think that they should be the way to do this also with curr-data type

Comment: For information, `curr(7,2)` doesn't mean 5 digits before [radix point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point), but 11: `curr`means a number in [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) format (i.e. 2 digits per byte, 1 half-byte used for the sign), `7` means a total of 7 bytes i.e. **13** digits + sign, and `2` of these 13 digits are after the radix point.

Comment: In ABAP Dictionary/CDS, prices with `curr` type refer to a currency code which drives the # of digits after the radix point: depending on currency, if the column contains 3.14, it means either 3.14 EUR or 314 JPY or 0.314 KWD-Kuwaiti Dinar (number of decimals defined in default TCURX table). More info: [CURRENCY_CONVERSION - CDS](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abencds_f1_conv_func_unit_curr.htm#!ABAP_VARIANT_2@2@) and [currency in ABAP dict.](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenddic_currency_field.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENDDIC_CURRENCY_FIELD_1)

Comment: Thank you, Sandra! Please write your comments as an answer, so I can mark it as a right answer as usual. BR. Denis.